# Why am I getting SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN error on NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, boringssl

Here is my code and I have not used Borring SSL anywhere

```
NSURL* urlToRequest = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest* urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urlToRequest];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

NSError *error = nil;

if (!error) {

    NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
            if (httpResp.statusCode == 200) {
                NSString *response1=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"JSON:%@",response1);
                NSLog(@"Response:%@",response);
                NSLog(@"Error:%@",error);

            }
        }
    }];

    [downloadTask resume];

}
```

Here is the error that I get and I am wondering what causes the issue ?

> [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2871
>   [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed
>   because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert

I am getting success response and after sometime I am getting this error.

As far as I understand its just a warning and I don't have to think about it.

Anyway I got successful response.Please correct me If I was wrong

Any suggestions are welcome

P.S
When I copy paste the URL in browser I don't see any error as well

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I've got a Swift 4, Xcode 9 project that's giving me this.

Comment: @Dale - I was keep on getting it.If you find the fix please do let me know

Answer (score -1):

Try with this

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSData *requestData = [prams dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@“GET”];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    //NSLog(@"data=%@",data);

    if (data.length>0 && error==nil) {
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];
        NSLog(@"Dict=%@",dict);


    }
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

Comment: It didn't fix the issue.